Can one binary use both lazy binding and non-lazy binding?
I inspected /bin/rm binary on macOS with the next command:  otool -l /bin/rm  | grep symbol_ptr -A5 and I've got the next output:
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100004000
      size 0x0000000000000008
    offset 16384
     align 2^3 (8)
--
  sectname __la_symbol_ptr
   segname __DATA
      addr 0x0000000100004028
      size 0x0000000000000148
    offset 16424
     align 2^3 (8)

I know the following:
__nl_symbol_ptr: Non lazy (bind at load) symbol pointer
__la_symbol_ptr: Lazy (bind on use) symbol pointer
Does it mean that /bin/rm binary uses both Lazy and Non lazy bindings?
